# Skipping first value in python for loop

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration

```
e = 'NewCamelCaseWord'
new_word = []

def snake_case_formatter(c, sep='-'):
    for i in list(c):
        if i.isupper():
            new_word.append(sep)
            i = i.lower()
        new_word.append(i)
    else:
        if new_word[0] == sep:
            del new_word[0]
        word = ''.join(new_word)
        return word
```

Hi this is my code to change camel case function names into snake case ones. When creating this function i did it by changing the string into a list and then adding spaces into the space before an upper case letter however this also meant that there would be a space before the beginning of the word. This meant when i joined the string together using dashes as separators there would be a dash at the beginning of the function name. I fixed the issue by deleting the first character in the else function but. How can I make it so that the loop skips the first letter if it is a uppercase letter? I tried using continue like this:

```
def snake_case_formatter(c, sep='-'):
    for i in list(c):
        if i.isupper():
            if i[0]:
                continue
            new_word.append(sep)
            i = i.lower()
        new_word.append(i)
    else:
        word = ''.join(new_word)
        return word
```

however it just messed up the code. So i assume it has something to do with my indentation but I'm not sure how exactly i am supposed to format it.

EDIT: I would like to know how to use continue in order to skip adding a space before the first letter in my string instead of having to delete it afterwards

Comment: Remove the `>` from your code. It's annoying when we try to run it

Comment: Could you rephrase the question? It's hard to understand exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Python is sensitive to indentation. the indentation determines if a statement is part of the `if` or `for` or not. I fixed the indentation.

Comment: Hi @Sven where did you fix the indentation exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the below code for expected solution:

```
e = 'CamelCaseWord'
new_word = []

range(len(e))
def snake_case_formatter(c, sep='-'):
    for i in range(len(e)):
        if i==0 and e[i].isupper():
            continue
        elif e[i].isupper()==True:
            new_word.append('-' + e[i].lower())
        else: 
            new_word.append(e[i])
    print(''.join(new_word))

snake_case_formatter(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

In `for i in list(c):` your variable `i` is the element of the list, not its index. It does not have information about the current index anymore.

`i[0]` is trying to access the first element of `i`, which probably doesn't make a lot of sense.

Python offers the function `enumerate` for iterating over elements together with their indices:

`for index, i in enumerate(list(c))`

Then `index` is the current index in the loop, which you can compare against `0`, for example with `if index==0:`.

Comment: Hi i tried what you said however I was looking for help on how the continue should be indented within the loop so that the first letter can be added without the space

Comment: For example if i try to input "CamelCaseWord" it returns "amel-case-word"

Comment: Well, you want to always append `i`, but the decision to skip the separator comes before that, so `continue` may not be a good solution. Just use the `if` to skip `append(sep)`.